# Safely and properly monkeypatching the require function in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, commonjs

Monkeypatching the require function in node.js may prove useful, especially for some libraries. I am trying to figure out how I could do it right, safely, etc.

Here is what I have:

```
const Mod = require('module');

const req = Mod.prototype.require;

Mod.prototype.require = function () {
  // do some side-effect of your own
  req.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

however this isn't quite working and I am not sure why. I get this error from with the debug module:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'init' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/alexamil/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/sumanjs/suman/node_modules/debug/src/node.js:15:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at Module.Mod.require (/Users/alexamil/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/sumanjs/suman/lib/index.js:11:9)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/alexamil/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/sumanjs/suman/node_modules/debug/src/index.js:9:20)
```

if my code is OK, then maybe I should take a closer look at what the debug module is doing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't return the result:

```
Mod.prototype.require = function () {
  // do some side-effect of your own
  return req.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

Without that `return` your wrapper always returns `undefined`.